# Flutter Navigator - push to the same page

Tags: flutter

how is the best way to push to the same page?

I have route A>B>C

and now, at page C I want do action, and after it I want push to C, but remove old C from route, so:

I have:
A>B>C

And execute this code on Page C

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => C(param: myParam),
                  ),
                );
```

And I have A>B>C>C
How to change this code to get new route ' A>B>C' after second push to page C?
I just want delete last navigation from route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the same page you want to push, you could do:

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, C);
```

Which will pop current page (C) and push C.

Comment: It looks nice, but how I can pass parameters? As You see, I have (param: myParam),

Comment: Try with `Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, C, arguments: myParam);` and let me know if it works

Comment: Thank You, now it working, below my final solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sum up, my new solution:

```
      child: MaterialApp(
        onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,
        home: PgSelectStartup(),
      ),

// _getRoute
  Route<dynamic> _getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/C') {
      return _buildRoute(
          settings,
          new PgConsultationsView(
              consultation: settings.arguments as MyParamClass));
    }
```

And call it:

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, "/C",
                    arguments: myParam);
```